# Which skills can be leveled outside the raid?

Tags: escape-from-tarkov

Some skills can be leveled without even entering any map, because they gain experience on actions performed in stash or hideout. While the situation seems clear for *Hideout Management* and *Crafting* - those are improved through appropriate actions in the Hideout - some other skills are not clearly documented as to when they can or cannot be improved.

Are there other skills that are not (exclusively) leveled while actually playing the game as PMC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, at least one more skill gains experience through actions in stash:

- Weapon maintenance: Experience is gained through repairing weapons

Experience is gained through actions in hideout for these skills:

- Hideout Management
- Crafting

These skills appear broken:

- Metabolism: Appears to gain experience through actions in stash, but progress is lost upon reloading profile (e.g. entering a raid)
- Intellect: Neither has effect nor gains experience outside of raid

All others skills: Only gain experience in raid (progress is saved to PMC/Scav character) or through quests that upon completion add fixed amounts of experience points or levels.

Comment: As of version `0.12.12.15`, starting likely on January 8th 2022, the skill *Weapon Maintenance* does not progress whatsoever due to a known bug.

Comment: As of version `0.12.12.30` the skill Weapon Maintenance works again - in conjunction with the newly introduced repair kits.

Comment: As of version `0.13.0.2` the maintenance skill has been joined by its siblings "light vests" and "heavy vests", and Strength and Endurance can be levelled through the newly added Hideout zone.